# Change heroku environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an app up and running on heroku connected to it's own database, however i have a database in my own server which is free and I want to connect my app to it, I changed my Gemfile accordingly but it seems to just ignore it.

I tried

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=url
```

but it said he couldn't replace the existing DATABASE_URL...

Comment: ohhh :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do this via the command line by first removing and then adding the variable:

```
heroku config:remove DATABASE_URL
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=http://someurl.com
```

or you can do this via the [heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps).

1. Select your app
2. Go to Settings
3. Reveal config variables
4. Change your DATABASE_URL